# Does texture mapping in openGL follows the forward texture mapping of the inverse method?

Tags: c++, opengl, texture-mapping

I've recently read that there are 2 types of texture mapping: forward (point-to-point) and inverse (area-to-area) mapping. Which one of them does OpenGL follows in the mapping process ?

Comment: what have you already searched and haven't you found?  Also, how do you know that there are only those two possibilities?   It would be more interesting if you asked something about the problem you are trying to solve that is dependent on a specific behavior.

Comment: I'm preparing a background chapter in my thesis and i wanted to add the type of texture mapping that OpenGL uses

Comment: I would guess that it's not defined.  You want to allow flexibility in compliant hardware/software combinations as well as not hamstring yourself with respect to forthcoming technologies.  If that assumption is correct, you would have to find the particular implementation of the driver you're interested in - which would probably be determined by the hardware on the device the driver is supporting.

Comment: That is a guess -- I take no responsibility for your thesis defense going poorly.

Comment: "*forward (point-to-point) and inverse (area-to-area) mapping*" ... what do "point" and "area" refer to in this context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It uses the "inverse" approach. Texture coordinates are rasterized (into fragments) and those are looked up per-fragment.